# VS2017 15.5.1 SSDT Security Change from TripleDES to AES256-CBC?

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption, ssis

I am working to establish a CI pipeline for SSIS, with the first step automating the creation of ISPAC deployment packages. I am using the code from: https://github.com/rtumaykin/ssis-build which creates ssisbuild.exe. The executable reads the XML from dtproj, unencrypting secured information using CrptoAPIs for TripleDES as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/security/access-control-for-sensitive-data-in-packages)

These two lines of code

```
var passwordDeriveBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, rgbSalt);

 cryptoServiceProvider.Key = passwordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, cryptoServiceProvider.IV);
```

Supply the password and salt from the dtproj file (converted to byte array with Convert.FromBase64String(saltXMLAttributeNode.Value)

The TripleDES conversion generates the exceptions:
"Specified initialization {IV} does not match the block size for this algorithm."

Looking into the VS2017 15.5 dtproj XML I find this section:

> SSIS:Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc">

Indicating the DTPROJ Encryption Algorithm is now aes256-cbc.

And in fact, changing the code to use:

```
   cryptoServiceProvider.Key = passwordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey("AES", "SHA1", 256, cryptoServiceProvider.IV);
```

Removes the error.
But the next lines:

```
        var passwordDeriveBytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(password, rgbSalt);

        cryptoServiceProvider.Key = passwordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey("AES", "SHA1", 256, cryptoServiceProvider.IV)
```

Generates the new non-descript error:

> "Object identifier (OID) is unknown"

Rewriting the decryption process using the examples in the AESCrptoServiceProvder Class from System.Security.Cryptography.Aes

using:

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytesAes(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] key, byte[] aesiv)
        {
            if (ciphertext == null || ciphertext.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cypherText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <=0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (aesiv == null || aesiv.Length <=0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("AESIV");
            string plaintext = null;
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.IV = aesiv;
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(ciphertext))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrtypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            plaintext = srDecrtypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext;
        }
```

where Key = the Salt value from dtproj generates an error

> "The specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm."

when loading the key at line:

```
 using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
```

I am either supplying the incorrect value for the key or using the incorrect CryptoServiceProvider.

Does anyone know how encryption has been changed in VS2017 SSDT 15.5.1?